# Magento 2.4, Error occurs when adding or modifying products in admin, how do I resolve this?

Tags: product, admin, error, magento2.4

```
Error: Class 'Magento\Catalog\Observer\SetSpecialPriceStartDate' not found in /var/www/html/mage/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:121 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/mage/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(108): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject() #1 /var/www/html/mage/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create() #2 /var/www/html/mage/vendor/magento/framework/Event/ObserverFactory.php(33): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() #3 /var/www/html/mage/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(72): Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverFactory->get() #4 /var/www/html/mage/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Manager.php(66): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->dispatch() #5 /var/www/html/mage/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Event/Manager/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager->dispatch() #6 /var/www/html/mage/vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php(702): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy->dispatch() #7 /var/www/html/mage/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/AbstractModel.php(383): Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel->beforeSave() #8 /var/www/html/mage/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product.php(935): Magento\Catalog\Model\AbstractModel->beforeSave() #9 /var/www/html/mage/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Product/Interceptor.php(230): Magento\Catalog\Model\Product->beforeSave() #10 /var/www/html/mage/vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/Observer/BeforeEntitySave.php(34): Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor->beforeSave() #11 /var/www/html/mage/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(88): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Observer\BeforeEntitySave->execute() #12 /var/www/html/mage/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(74): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->_callObserverMethod() #13 /var/www/html/mage/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Manager.php(66): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->dispatch() #14 /var/www/html/mage/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Event/Manager/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager->dispatch() #15 /var/www/html/mage/vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/EventManager.php(51): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy->dispatch() #16 /var/www/html/mage/vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/Operation/Create.php(116): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\EventManager->dispatchEntityEvent() #17 /var/www/html/mage/vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/EntityManager.php(96): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Operation\Create->execute() #18 /var/www/html/mage/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product.php(764): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\EntityManager->save() #19 /var/www/html/mage/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product->save() #20 /var/www/html/mage/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor->___callParent() #21 /var/www/html/mage/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Indexer/Fulltext/Plugin/Product.php(58): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() #22 /var/www/html/mage/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Indexer/Fulltext/Plugin/Product.php(28): Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Plugin\Product->addCommitCallback() #23 /var/www/html/mage/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Plugin\Product->aroundSave() #24 /var/www/html/mage/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() #25 /var/www/html/mage/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Interceptor.php(194): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor->___callPlugins() #26 /var/www/html/mage/vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php(655): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor->save() #27 /var/www/html/mage/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Product/Interceptor.php(1706): Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel->save() #28 /var/www/html/mage/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Save.php(143): Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor->save() #29 /var/www/html/mage/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save->execute() #30 /var/www/html/mage/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save\Interceptor->___callParent() #31 /var/www/html/mage/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Plugin/ActionFlagNoDispatchPlugin.php(51): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() #32 /var/www/html/mage/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Plugin\ActionFlagNoDispatchPlugin->aroundExecute() #33 /var/www/html/mage/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() #34 /var/www/html/mage/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Save/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save\Interceptor->___callPlugins() #35 /var/www/html/mage/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(111): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save\Interceptor->execute() #36 /var/www/html/mage/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(151): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch() #37 /var/www/html/mage/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch() #38 /var/www/html/mage/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save\Interceptor->___callParent() #39 /var/www/html/mage/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() #40 /var/www/html/mage/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch() #41 /var/www/html/mage/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() #42 /var/www/html/mage/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Save/Interceptor.php(32): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save\Interceptor->___callPlugins() #43 /var/www/html/mage/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(186): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save\Interceptor->dispatch() #44 /var/www/html/mage/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(118): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest() #45 /var/www/html/mage/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch() #46 /var/www/html/mage/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent() #47 /var/www/html/mage/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() #48 /var/www/html/mage/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins() #49 /var/www/html/mage/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(116): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch() #50 /var/www/html/mage/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() #51 /var/www/html/mage/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(263): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() #52 /var/www/html/mage/pub/index.php(29): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() #53 {main}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a default file of Magento so check if this was accidentally deleted. Did you add some modules or did an upgrade.

Comment: Possibly, but this server is just for testing and this feature isn't currently needed, so I simply commented out the event in event.xml. It is a hack but it is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is not an ideal solution, but I disabled the event and I am now able to make product edits in admin.

Answer (score 0):

- Run composer clearcache && composer install to get all file missing.
- If the file is not found. You should create an apply patch to add it in.